# Foreach-statement in c++ and language extension?

Tags: c++, syntax, macros, foreach

You can simulate foreach-statement in c++ with macro declaration. I'm using similar syntax for looping arrays in the following way:

```
int array1[10];
vector<int> array2(10);

fori(array1)
    forj(array2)
        fork(123)
             if(array1[i]==array[j])
                  return true;
```

What's your favorite macros for extending c++ language in some way?

EDIT:

Implementation of the macro mentioned in the question is:

```
#define fori(a) for(int i=0;i<getsize(a);i++)
#define forj(a) for(int j=0;j<getsize(a);j++)
#define foru(a) for(int u=0;u<getsize(a);u++)
#define fork(a) for(int k=0;k<getsize(a);k++)
#define forl(a) for(int l=0;l<getsize(a);l++)

template<typename T>
int getsize(T& v ){return v.size();}
template<typename T,int N>
int getsize(T(&v)[N]){return N;}
int getsize(int v){return v;}
```

Comment: My 2¢: the use of the std::for_each template is more appropriate than using a macro.

Comment: Perhaps you could at least share the implementations of your macros.

Comment: Why didn't you just take the variable as a parameter in the macro, so you have one macro for an unlimited number of variable names? Rather than the ones you write by hand.

Comment: Because my code uses lots of looping. When you have cpp-file with 10 functions, and every one of them start with a loop, it seems excessive to write BOOST_FOREACH(int& i, xxx) every time. Even when using visual studio's auto-complete-feature (in c#) it starts getting on my nerves.. all those repeating characters and iterator types in some specific order. And usually I'm not even against code duplication. I guess it's those special characters like commas and semicolons that get on my nerves. :)

Comment: Before you share maybe you should write them to conform with what people expect language extensions to look like. foreach already has a definition in several languages maybe looking at those would help you write a beter one at the moment yours is nearly useless.

Comment: Yes Martin, this solution seems non-standard and hackish, but believe it or not it grows on you. In my experience language extensions are practically always nearly useless. That's why I was positively surprised when this looping-macro persisted in my code week after week. Normally when programming for fun (not at work) I get bored with language extensions and macros and drop them really fast. My hobby project is in constant and never-ending refactoring state. :)

Comment: This code is also bad because it doesn't use iterators, which are far more useful than simply returning the index.

Comment: If 9 times of 10 I loop through arrays, I would much rather use special cased solution for looping though maps and linked lists. Of course you can argue that special cased solutions lead to complexity, and generalized solution covers most of the use-cases and thus is easier to re-use. I disagree. You should keep your code as simple as possible, everything else belongs to YAGNI-universe.

Answer (score 8):

You should check out [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach.html).

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(5);
BOOST_FOREACH(int& i, v)
{
    i = i * i;
}
```

Comment: Well you're using your own version aren't you? Yes, Boost.Foreach works very well.

Comment: Yeah, it's great for writing fast, understandable code. Much better than the macro you're using.

Comment: i love it. BOOST_FOREACH, boost::function and boost::shared_ptr << never wanna miss you!

Comment: +1.  Boost foreach is neat.  You may already be aware but your example would benefit from boost assign too!  v += 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5;

Comment: The only thing I hate about boost foreach is it's too loud in the morning shouting like that.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason I need to *skip* STL containers I use this macro for my container classes:

```
#define M_foreach( iterable ) \
do {\
  (iterable).prepareit();\
  while (  (iterable).stepit()  ) {

#if !defined( M_end )
#  define M_end   } } while( 0 );
#endif
```

(that macro *assumes* that you use a container that has an **iteration interface**)

```
Container foo;
M_foreach ( foo )
   ...
   Container bar;
   M_foreach ( bar )
      ...
   M_end
   ...
M_end
```

Answer (score 0):

I find boost's macro a bit cumbersome.

Here's my attempt:

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
#define FOR_EACH(cont, iter)    \   
  for (BOOST_TYPEOF(cont)::const_iterator iter = cont.begin(), e = cont.end(); \
    iter != e; \
    ++iter)
```

Works for standard containers.

Used like so:

```
vector<int> vi;
// ...
FOR_EACH(vi, i)
  cout << *i;
```

Supports nesting:

```
map<string, list<int> > msli;
msli["key1"].push_back(1);
msli["key1"].push_back(2);
msli["key2"].push_back(3);
msli["key2"].push_back(4);

FOR_EACH(msli, i) {
  cout << i->first << endl;
  FOR_EACH(i->second, j)
    cout << "\t" << *j << endl;
}

/*
Prints:
  key1
    1
    2
  key2
    3
    4
*/
```

Source: http:/wtw.tw/papers/foreach.html